# Help on complex number question

Tags: complex-numbers

$z-c=\rho\displaystyle\frac{1+it}{1-it}$

where c is complex, $\rho$ is real and t is a real parameter. I substituted z=x+iy and tried to equate the real and imaginary parts. Is this method wrong or would I consider the case c=a+ib since the question states that c is complex.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1-it=\overline{1+it}\,$, therefore $|1-it|=|1+it|\,$. Then taking the magnitudes on both sides:

$$|z-c|=|\rho|\,\left|\frac{1+it}{1-it}\right|=|\rho| \quad \iff \quad \bbox[10px,border:1px solid]{\rho = \pm|z-c|}$$

- If $z=c$ then $\rho=0$ and $t$ is undefined.
- Else if $z-c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\rho=z-c$ and $t=0\,$ (the other sign doesn't work, since $\cfrac{1+it}{1-it}= -1$ has no solutions).
- Otherwise, substituting $\rho$ back and solving for $t\,$:
  $$
  \rho(1+it) = (z-c)(1-it) \;\;\iff\;\; (\rho+z-c)it=z-c-\rho \;\;\iff\;\; t = i\,\frac{\rho-z+c}{\rho+z-c}
  $$
  With $w=\cfrac{z-c}{\rho}=\cfrac{z-c}{\pm |z-c|}\,$ so that $|w|=1\,$, the latter expression for $t$ can be rewritten as:
  $$\require{cancel}t=i\cfrac{1-w}{1+w}=i\cfrac{(1-w)(1+\bar w)}{(1+w)(1+\bar w)}=i\,\frac{\cancel{1} - \cancel{w \bar w} - w + \bar w}{1+w \bar w + w + \bar w}=i \, \frac{-2i \operatorname{Im}(w)}{2+2\operatorname{Re}(w)}=\frac{\operatorname{Im}(w)}{1+\operatorname{Re}(w)} \\[5px]
  \iff\quad\;\; \bbox[10px,border:1px solid]{t=\cfrac{\operatorname{Im}(z-c)}{\pm|z-c|+\operatorname{Re}(z-c)}}\,$$

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you must set $c=a+i b$ since $c$ is said to be complex.

Start with the rhs first$$\frac{1+it}{1-it}=\frac{(1+it)^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2}$$ so, now,
$$(x+iy)-(a+ib)=\rho\left(\frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2} \right)$$

Just continue.

Comment: But I'm getting stuck on the final stp. Ie when trying to substitute c with a and b. But my intuition tells me there's no way to substitute it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=a+ib$, $c=\alpha + i\beta$, $x=(a-\alpha)$, $y=(b-\beta)$

$$z-c = (a+ib)-(\alpha+i\beta)=(a-\alpha)+i(b-\beta)= x + iy$$

$$\rho \frac{1+it}{1-it} = \rho \frac{1+it}{1-it} \cdot \frac{1+it}{1+it} =  \rho \frac{(1+it)^2}{1+t^2}=\rho \frac{1-t^2+i2t}{1+t^2}=\frac{\rho(1- t^2)}{1+ t^2}+ \frac{i2t \rho}{1+t^2}$$

Then

$$x=\frac{\rho(1- t^2)}{1+ t^2} \qquad y=\frac{2t \rho}{1+t^2}$$

Now you just need to solve for $\rho$ and $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$